# Need help / Creating Methods via prototype property

Tags: javascript

Please help me to understand below code. This is the script for drag and drop object. I am trying to explore it but struck at one thing.

[URL for Reference (Complete Script)](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/InternetWeb/Conceptual/SafariVisualEffectsProgGuide/InteractiveVisualEffects/InteractiveVisualEffects.html)

I dont understand how this method creation work, like get x(), set x() etc. Is `get` and `Set` is predefined object? will it actually set object value or get specific value of object, like we have in date object.

Also there is one space between its declaration `set x()`, why?

I am new to java script, i really appreciate your help.

```
// position strings are "x,y" with no units
get x()
{
    return parseInt(this._position.split(',')[0]);
},

set x(inX)
{
    var comps = this._position.split(',');   
    comps[0] = inX;
    this.position = comps.join(',');
},

get y()
{
    return parseInt(this._position.split(',')[1]);
},

set y(inY)
{
    var comps = this._position.split(',');
    comps[1] = inY;
    this.position = comps.join(',');
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start by calling the language 'JavaScript' not 'java script'; [the language is standardized as Ecmascript](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm).

[Look up creation of methods in Ecmascript (JavaScript)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript). The functions set(inX) and get() are methods be of some prototype - the clue is the this reference referencing the current instance. However, one should write function get(), and function set(inX) instead.

From Wikipedia:

> Prototype-based
>
> prototypes
>
> JavaScript uses prototypes instead of classes for inheritance. It
>   is possible to simulate many class-based features with prototypes in
>   JavaScript. functions as object constructors
>
> Functions double as object constructors along with their typical
>   role. Prefixing a function call with new creates a new object and
>   calls that function with its local this keyword bound to that object
>   for that invocation. The constructor's prototype property determines
>   the object used for the new object's internal prototype. JavaScript's
>   built-in constructors, such as Array, also have prototypes that can be
>   modified. functions as methods
>
> Unlike many object-oriented languages, there is no distinction
>   between a function definition and a method definition. Rather, the
>   distinction occurs during function calling; a function can be called
>   as a method. When a function is called as a method of an object, the
>   function's local this keyword is bound to that object for that
>   invocation.